# How to know when all chunks are received

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing https request like this:

```
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers: ', res.headers);

    res.on('data', function (d) {
        // how to know when all chunks are received
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
req.end();
```

The response comes as JSON object, however I get it in my callback as buffer array and in multiple chunks (my callback is called several times). How do I know when all chunks are received? And how then can I convert this array buffer into JSON object?

Comment: `res.on('end', blah)` ??

Comment: thanks, do you suggest I write all the data on `data` callback into some variable and then on `end` callback I make the conversion from that variable's array buffer to json?

Comment: That would be the most preferred way unless you have some requirement where you must put the data chunk by chunk in stdout. :)
Also, it is a good practice to use callback function as a parameter and then call that callback function in your `.on('end')` with the received data.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide the code for your last suggestion _is a good practice to use callback function_? I'll then accept the answer

Comment: Sure. Can you tell me what is `https` in your code? Is it a simple `require('https')` or an alias for `require(`request`)` or something else altogether?

Comment: thanks, https is a simple `https` module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering as requested in the comments.

First thing is wrap your code in another function.

```
function getHttpsData(callback){ // pass additional parameter as callback
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers: ', res.headers);
        var response = '';

        res.on('data', function (d) {
            // how to know when all chunks are received
            //process.stdout.write(d);
            response+=d;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            var r = JSON.parse(response);
            callback(r); // Call the callback so that the data is available outside.
        });

    });
    req.end();
    req.on('error', function(){
        var r = {message:'Error'}; // you can even set the errors object as r.
        callback(r);
    });
}
```

And then call the `getHttpsData` function with a callbackfunction as a parameter.

```
getHttpsData(function(data){
    console.log(data);//data will be whatever you have returned from .on('end') or .on('error')
});
```

Comment: Solid answer, though I'd recommend either a) following the `node` convention of having separate `success` and `error` callback functions or I'd skip the callbacks and go with Promises instead.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher : Thanks! I will update the answer to reflect these things as well. :)